# Populating a dropdown list based on a value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list that I want to limit the options that are displayed based on another dropdown.
This is the html:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
    <option value="1,cell">AirTouch</option>
    <option value="2,page">AirTouch Alpha Pager</option>
    <option value="3,cell">Ameritech</option>
    <option value="4,cell">Arch</option>
    <option value="5,cell">AT&amp;T Wireless</option>
    <option value="6,cell">Bell Atlantic Mobile</option>
    <option value="7,email">SMTP</option>
</select>
```

This is the jquery function call when the user changes a value on the list:

```
$(document).on("change", "[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]", function () {
 if ($(this).is(":disabled") == false) {
     var DeviceSelValue = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").val();
     $(this).children("option").hide();
     $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
     alert('value: ' + $('option:selected', this).attr('value'));
     switch (DeviceSelValue) {
         case "1":
             $("option[value*='cell']", this).show();
             $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
             $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").show();
             break;
         case "2":                       
             $("option[value*='email']", this).show();
             $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
             $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").hide();
             break;
         case "3":
             $("option[value*='page']", this).show();
             $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
             $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").show();
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 }
});
```

The DeviceSelValue is properly set to 1 / 2 / 3.
But all of the options are shown regardless of the device option chosen.
The selected value is displayed correctly.
How can I set the list to only show the values that are either 'cell' / 'email' / 'page'.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Below is my ready function and after is the `bindevent` function.  The `bindevent` function is called after the code-behind insert change function.  But the `if` statement is never true.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Configure the DropDownBox using the 'chosen' jquery plugin
$(".chosen-single").chosen({
    search_contains: true,
    width: "200px",
    no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
});
...several other functions that are used when in edit mode
});

//bind events after partial page postback
$(function () {
bindEvents();
});

//This change function is when the Device grid is in Insert Mode
function bindEvents() {
alert('start bind event');

    $(document).on("change", "[id*=recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert]", function () {
        $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").prop("disabled", false);
        $("select:not(.chosen-select, .no-chosen)").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            width: "200px",
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
        });
        var DeviceSelValue = $(this).val();
        alert('bind event - device change event on insert. Device value: ' + DeviceSelValue);
        $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").val('');
        $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").children("option").hide();
        $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");

        switch (DeviceSelValue) {
            case "1":
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='cell']").show();
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").hide();
                break;
            case "2":
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='email']").show();
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").hide();
                break;
            case "3":
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='page']").show();
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").hide();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    //If this control is enabled, reset the list so the correct values are shown.
    if ($("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").is(":disabled") == false) {
        alert('bind event - in if statement');
        var DeviceSelValue = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").val();
        alert('disabled service insert - device select value: ' + DeviceSelValue);
        $(this).children("option").hide();
        $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");   
        switch (DeviceSelValue) {
            case "1":
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='cell']").show();
                alert('html: ' + $(this).html());
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("#recdevgvAddressExtInsert").show();
                break;
            case "2":
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='email']").show();
                alert('html: ' + $(this).html());
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("#recdevgvAddressExtInsert").hide();
                break;
            case "3":
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='page']").show();
                alert('html: ' + $(this).html());
                $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("#recdevgvAddressExtInsert").show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

The bind event function is called after the code-behind change function but the `if` statement is not true.

Comment: I like super simple solutions, basically, I would clean the dropdown with .empty() every time its changes, and the I would add just the options I need based on the deviceSelValue logic you need.

Comment: I made this simple code, I am not sure if the logic you need, but it shows how to remove depending of the selection... https://jsfiddle.net/3e35ygvt/

Comment: I tried your suggestion replacing `$("option[value*='page']", this).show();` with `$(".chosen-single option[value*='page']").show();`  But the list is not limiting.  It shows all of the options.  This dropdown list is in the insertion row of a nested gridview.  I think I have to use the `this` selector in some way so that the correct dropdown is updated.

Comment: I stand corrected.  That did set the options correctly but I have an event in the code-behind that is called afterward and it must be resetting the values so that all are visible.  This function needs to run after the code-behind event.  How can that be accomplished?

Comment: The event on the code behind is fired on purpose or is the Page_Load?

Comment: The event is fired on purpose.  Then the document.ready function on the client side.  But the values for the dropdown list are not limited by the option selected by the first dropdown.  It is because it is a nested grid.  I have a grid with this data on another page and it works correctly.  Because it is nested, I don't think the Ids of the dropdowns are correctly  identified.

Comment: Ohhh i see..., what about moving the code inside the function called on the On Change, to a regular function, and call it after the first dropdown is filled or set?

Comment: I guess I could but it is much faster to set the service name options from the client side since it is a matter or showing or hiding the values.  On the client side, I am calling a `bindEvent` function for partial postbacks.  It is called when the `document.ready()` function is not called.  I added an `if` statement when the insert dropdown is disabled but it is never true.  I added the   `bindEvent` function above after the `ready` function.

Comment: are you using .net c#? can you post more code including the ajax call?

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I used the `each` function and it worked.  The complete answer is below for anyone else who is struggling with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected my problem by adding the `each` function to my `bindEvents()` function.
Instead of an `if` statement I added an `each` function to trigger the update to the service name list.
This is the code:

```
//bind events after partial page postback
$(function () {
    bindEvents();
});

function bindEvents() {
    //...other function calls like change events with other controls

    $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":disabled") == false) {
            var DeviceSelValue = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").val();
            UpdateServiceNameOptions(this, DeviceSelValue);
        }
    });  //end service name each function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple: split the destination dropdown in 3 different dropdowns mapping the target behavior. Then you can show the target dropdown depending on the user's selection and hide the not necessary ones (e.g. the ones containing the options you want to hide)